# Swift 3 - Push segue to navigation controller

Tags: swift, swift3

In my storyboard I have a View Controller, I also have a Navigation Controller and another View Controller called HistoryController. The Navigation Controller and the HistroyController have a relationship "root view controller"

I have a button on my 1st View Controller and that button has a push segue to the Navigation Controller.

I have this code in the 1st View Controller to to prepare the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let viewController = segue.destination as? HistoryController {
            viewController.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
        }

    }
```

my problem is when I run my code and push the button in my first controller, I get this error:

```
Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'HistorySegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

My question is, why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

I have tried the following

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController{
            if let historyVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as? HistoryController{
                historyVC.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
        if let vc = nav.visibleViewController as? HistoryController {
            vc.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
        }
    }
}
```

and I still get the same error:

```
Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'HistorySegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

Comment: it will help you display your storyboard

Answer (score 12):

You need to embed your source view controller in a Navigation Controller or change the segue kind from push to something else. Also, try and cast your destination controller to UINavigationController to prevent a different error after the initial one if fixed:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController{
            if let historyVC = navVC.viewControllers[0] as? HistoryController{
                historyVC.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
            }
        }
    }
```

See if that works for you.

EDIT: Updated the code above.

Comment: I changed my code to yours and I get this error `Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'detailItem'`

Comment: use  let controller = viewController.topViewController
            controller.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in your code, that is fine, it is in your storyboard.

If you would like to push to HistoryVC from ViewController, ViewController should be embedded in a UINavigationController, not HistoryVC (it would be embedded implicitly by it's relationship with ViewController).

The reason for this is that the VC that is pushing must be embedded in a UINavigationController, the vc that is being pushed is inherently embedded because it is added to the UINavigationController's stack.

[image]

If the initial ViewController is not within a UINavigationController, there is no stack for the pushed ViewController (HistoryVC) to be pushed onto. Basically, you embed your starting point for your stack (Your first ViewController) in the UINavigationController.

If you want to start a new stack a few VCs down the line you can embed the next view controller in a new UINavigationController, that however you would need to segue to modally.

Comment: how did you generate this image?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController{
        if let historyVC = navVC.childViewControllers[0] as? HistoryController{
            historyVC.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `show` segue instead of `push` segue.

The show segue will push the next viewController into the first viewcontroller's navigationController stack whenever possible, otherwise it   will use `modalPresent` to show the next viewController.

If you embed your 1st viewController into a UINavigationController, and still keep your Navigation Controller,then you use `push` segue, you will get a exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Simple change your segue from `push` to `show` should fit in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
        if let vc = nav.visibleViewController as? HistoryController {
            vc.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says "you can't use a push segue if your source (1 st viewController) is not embedded in a navigationController.

You need to to change the type of your segue from "push" to "presentModally" - Normally that should work.
You can still segue to the navigationController but not with a push - push only works inside of NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

> In my storyboard I have a View Controller, I also have a Navigation Controller and another View Controller called HistoryController. The Navigation Controller and the HistroyController have a relationship "root view controller"
>
> I have a button on my 1st View Controller and that button has a push segue to the Navigation Controller.

Now here's your problem. In your storyboard you should have a `rootViewController` relationship between the `UINavigationController` and `FirstViewController` and **not** to `HistoryController`. Then, the button in your `FirstViewController` should have a push segue connection to `HistoryController`. See the following picture:

[image]

Also, the app entry point should be the `UINavigationController` (just drag the little left sided arrow or select the `UINavigationController` and in the right side pannel check `Is initial controller`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to push a segue using a `UIViewController`, not a `UINavigationController`.

Setup your storyboard the following way:
[image]

As you might see, the first view controller is showing the segue to the second view controller, what is wrapped in a navigation controller.

This way, when you fire your segue, just use the following code to access your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let historyVC = segue.destination as? HistoryController {
      // do what you need to.
        }
 }
```

If you do not need a separate `UINavigationController` specifically to `HistoryController`, than you can just remove the one above `HistoryController`, and use the one attached to the first view controller.

Answer (score 0):

To use the push segue ViewController needs to be embedded in the NavigationController. If you don't want ViewController to be part of NavigationController's view controllers stack you could remove in HistoryController using:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([self], animated: false)
}
```

An alternative is to have a segue from ViewController to NavigationController that is not a push segue, e.g. Present Modally or custom if you want to control the way the NavigationController shows in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the identifier also?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController where segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifierSetInTheStoryboard"{
    if let vc = nav.visibleViewController as? HistoryController {
        vc.detailItem = barcodeInt as AnyObject
    }
  }
}
```